# Can't display PHP arrays in Ajax success callback

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I created a simple registration form in php and made validations for user inputs. I gave to each `$error[]` array a string index. Well in example its like: `$error['fn']` I did this because I want to show each validation error *next to/below to* user input with Ajax json data type. But for some reason only one of the arrays output displays, the other output not.

[image: Screenshot]

It should be show the other output below the username input.
How can I display the other output and where am I making a mistake?

```
<?php

require('../includes/config.php');

if(isset($_POST['fullname'])){
    //fullname validation
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];

    if (empty($_POST['fullname'])) {
        $error['fn'] = "Please fill this field";
        echo json_encode($error);
        
    }
    if (! $user->isValidFullname($fullname)){
        $error['fn'] = 'Your name must be alphabetical characters';
        echo json_encode($error);
        
    }   
        
}

if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    //username validation
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    
    if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
        $error['un'] = "Please fill this field";
        echo json_encode($error);
        
    }
    if (! $user->isValidUsername($username)){
        $error['un'] = 'Your username must be at least 3 alphanumeric characters';
        echo json_encode($error);
        
    }
    if (! $user->isUsernameAlreadyinUse($username)){
        $error['un'] = 'This username already in use';
        echo json_encode($error);
        
    }       
}
?>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#register-form").on("submit", function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var fullname = $("#fullname").val();
            var username = $("#username").val();            
       
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "registercontrol.php",
                data: {
                    fullname: fullname,
                    username: username
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(result) {
                    $("#vfullname").html(result['fn']);
                    $("#vusername").html(result['un']);                    
                }
            });         
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where in the PHP do you echo something when NOT in error? Also encode the array and echo ONCE

Comment: You shouldn't be making any `echo` until the very end of your script.

Comment: Wow @Nick thank you for that. Its so easy to fix but can't see front of my eyes.

Comment: @Ulrich no worries - sometimes you just need a second set of eyes

Comment: @Nick its true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after success function kindly add

```
data = JSON.parse(result);
$("#vfullname").html(data.fn);
$("#vusername").html(data.un);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, it's working. But the actual problem is in my php if else statements. I echoed arrays inside of every statements. So this breaks outputs. Well if I not make any echo until the very end of my script your answer can't works too.

Comment: Its not the real solution. Your javascript solution smilar to mines. Problem is in php echo. I answered my own answer depending on Nick's answer. See below.

Comment: he said put echo at end of the script. so i thought u've done already. datsy im correcting only the success function